# switch to gnome desktop enviroment

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

I want to know how do i switch to gnome desktop environment.
When I used this command to check which desktop environemnts are installed.

```
ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/
```

it showed this,

```
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  216 Mar 26  2015 gnome.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4806 Oct 31  2015 kde-plasma.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  213 Mar 26  2015 ubuntu.desktop
```

but when i logout to switch to gnome there was only option for `Ubuntu (default)` and `kde-plasma.`

No option for gnome. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.